# How can I return socket created by function and pass it to another?

Tags: python, multithreading, sockets, datagram

I would like to define function that creates socket, binds socket to specific address and port, get data from source(incessantly) and then return this socket so I could use it in other function. Is it possible? If so, how can I do that?

I would like to multithread `socket_analyser`, does it imply multithreading `socket_receiver` also?

The problem is that after invoking `socket_creator`, the function doesn't return `sock`. When I try to pass it to `socket_receiver` in `socket_analyser` it underline parameter `sock` saying it's not defined.

I also tried to define `testsocket = sock` just after `socket_creator(MCAST_GRP[0],MCAST_PORT)` to pass it to `socket_receiver(testsock, BUFFER_UDP)` however - the same result.

```
import socket
import struct
import time
import threading


MCAST_GRP = ['239.0.1.104','239.0.1.105']
MCAST_PORT = 12345
BUFFER_UDP = 2048

def socket_creator(multicast_group, multicast_port):

    MCAST_GRP = multicast_group
    MCAST_PORT = multicast_port    
    sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM, socket.IPPROTO_UDP)
    sock.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)   
    sock.bind(('', MCAST_PORT))
    mreq = struct.pack("4sl", socket.inet_aton(MCAST_GRP), socket.INADDR_ANY)
    sock.setsockopt(socket.IPPROTO_IP, socket.IP_ADD_MEMBERSHIP, mreq)
    return sock
#testsocket = sock

def socket_receiver(sockett, bufferUDP):
    BUFFER_UDP = bufferUDP
    sock_rcv = sockett
    for x in range(10):       
        data, address = sock_rcv.recvfrom(BUFFER_UDP)
        totalSize += len(data)
    return totalSize

def socket_analyser(multicast_group, multicast_port, totalSize):
    print("_____.:|   Starting analysis!   |:._____\n")
    print("͞◌͞◌͞◌͞◌͞.:|   IP: {}    PORT: {}  |:.͞◌͞◌͞◌͞͞◌͞◌".format(multicast_group,multicast_port))    
    socket_analyser(sock, BUFFER_UDP)
    print(totalSize)
    totalSize = 0

socket_creator(MCAST_GRP[0],MCAST_PORT)
socket_creator(MCAST_GRP[1],MCAST_PORT)

t1 = threading.Thread(target=socket_analyser, args=(MCAST_GRP[0],MCAST_PORT,BUFFER_UDP, sock))
t2 = threading.Thread(target=socket_analyser, args=(MCAST_GRP[1],MCAST_PORT,BUFFER_UDP, sock))

t1.start()
t2.start()

t1.join()
t2.join()

print('End of test')
time.sleep(5)
```

Thank you in advance for anything bringing me closer to the solution

Answer (score 1):

I am seeing a couple of logical issues in the code

1. **sock** object scope is only inside **socket_creator** so it would not be available outside unless you receive the return result into another variable
2. You are passing an undefined variable **sock** to the analyzer method
3. You are recursively calling **socket_analyser** method inside **socket_analyser** method

I just modified a few things to fix

```
def socket_analyser(BUFFER_UDP, sock):
    socket_receiver(sock, BUFFER_UDP)
    print(BUFFER_UDP)


sock1 = socket_creator(MCAST_GRP[0],MCAST_PORT)
sock2 = socket_creator(MCAST_GRP[1],MCAST_PORT)

t1 = threading.Thread(target=socket_analyser, args=(BUFFER_UDP, sock1))
t2 = threading.Thread(target=socket_analyser, args=(BUFFER_UDP, sock2))
```